# Setting alternate column colors for grid using Flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

So, if you head over to http://www.flotcharts.org/ and look at the grid in the demo at the top of the page, you will see that each column has an alternate color, much like alternate row colors in tables.

I have searched all over, looked at the code for the site but for the life of me I cannot figure out how this is done. It seems to have something to do with the markings function but alas, I have had no success. Any one been able to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use markings, as described in the [Customizing the Grid](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-grid) section of the API docs.  You can see how it's done in that demo by [viewing the source](http://www.flotcharts.org/javascript/flot.demo.js), which is (purposely) not minified.

Comment: Thanks DNS! I thought it was the marking function, guess I need to reads the docs in more detail.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery "odd" with appropriate HTML and CSS as follows:

```
$(function () {
    $(".col:odd").children().css('background', 'white');
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjuHA/

Comment: Flot uses canvas; the columns are rendered, not HTML elements.